# I'm getting some unknown requests in my "app engine" aplicattion and want to know what they are

Tags: firebase, ssl, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-404

it's just a simple express js web app in standard environment, i put my custom domain and is working ok,
but a couple of days ago I started receiving these requests and I want to know what they are.

[image: App engine panel]

[image: Logging]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those requests are typically Let's Encrypt requests to verify that you control the domain during the SSL certificate validation process.

The response is `404 Not Found` which means the pages do not exist.

Those requests are harmless provided that you do not receive a massive number of requests.